# C++/Win32 constructor not initializing variable with string obtained from dialog

Tags: c++, win32gui

I'm trying to get create an object with a std::string obtained from a dialog box, when debugging I see that is is successfully obtained and passed to the constructor, however the local param stays as "".

This is my class header:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include <istream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

class Motorcycle
{
public:
    Motorcycle();
    Motorcycle(const std::string& nameP, int mileage) : name(nameP), mileage(mileage) {};

    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream & out, const Motorcycle & obj)
    {
        out << obj.name << "\n" << obj.mileage << std::endl;
        return out;
    };

    //friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in, const Motorcycle & obj)
    //{
    //  in >> &obj.name[0] >> obj.mileage;
    //  return in;
    //};

private:
    std::string name;
    int mileage;
};
```

The cpp is empty still (I thought maybe I should put the constructor there, but the result was the same?):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Motorcycle.h"
#include <string>

Motorcycle::Motorcycle()
{
}

//Motorcycle::Motorcycle(const std::string &nameP, int mileage) : name(nameP), mileage(mileage) {};
```

This is the proc for the dialog plus the other functions:

```
    BOOL CALLBACK CreateBikeProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    std::string name = "";
    int mileage;

    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_INITDIALOG:

        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam))
        {
        case IDOK:
            GetDlgItemTextA(hWnd, IDC_EDIT_NAME, &name[0], 16);
            mileage = GetDlgItemInt(hWnd, IDC_EDIT_MILEAGE, NULL, FALSE);
            if (ValidateBike(name, mileage))
            {
                CreateBike(name, mileage);
                EndDialog(hWnd, IDOK);
            }
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hWnd, IDCANCEL);
            break;
        }
        break;
    default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

BOOL ValidateBike(std::string& name, int mileage)
{
    if (name[0] == ' ' || name.find_first_not_of(' ') != name.npos
        || mileage < 1)
        return false;
    
    return true; 
}
BOOL CreateBike(std::string& name, int mileage)
{

    Motorcycle bike = Motorcycle(name, mileage);
    
    std::ofstream ofs("motorcycles.txt", std::ios::app);
    ofs << bike;
    ofs.close();

    return true;
}
```

I can see that name in CreateBikeProc is assigned and passed to the other functions, but then bike.name is empty...

Additionally, the `friend std::istream & operator >>` is commented out because it causes another error...
`Error  1   error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::istream' (or there is no acceptable conversion)`

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Motorcycle bike = new Motorcycle(name, mileage);` ?

Comment: No it shouldn't, @devb. This is C++, not Java.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik very true, and sorry. Though in my case it's C# I got mixed up  :-D.

Comment: Well, as a half-answer (or maybe quarter-answer): Your `>>` overload won't work as it is because you've declared the `Motorcycle` argument as `const` … and you can't input data from a stream or anywhere else into a `const`. Also, `name` is a `std::string` ***not a char array*** so use `in >> obj.name >> obj.mileage;` (not `&obj.name[0]`).

Comment: I believe the problem lies in how you access the buffer of the name variable that you pass to the GetDlgItemTextA function. You should either allocate memory for it, or have it returned through appropriate member functions and std:string

Comment: Thanks Adrian, that was correct!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
GetDlgItemTextA(hWnd, IDC_EDIT_NAME, &name[0], 16);
```

You cannot read a value into a string like this. You need to create a buffer, and then update the string from the buffer:

```
char buffer[17]="";
GetDlgItemTextA(hWnd, IDC_EDIT_NAME, &buffer, 16);
name=buffer;
```

For `operator>>`, you have two problems: the first is the `const Motorcycle` argument, and the second is that you are trying to overwrite the string in-place. Here is a fixed version:

```
    friend std::istream & operator >> (std::istream & in, Motorcycle & obj)
    {
      in >> obj.name >> obj.mileage;
      return in;
    };
```

Comment: Please feel free to add the 'fix` for `>>` I gave in my comment! Then it will be both a *good* answer and a *complete* one.

Comment: Thanks to you both :D